# Winter 15 Release and WSDL issue on Apex Class

Tags: webservices, apex

I am relatively new to apex classes and web services but have been getting on fine until I upgraded the Sandbox of a clients environment to the Winter '15 release. Now when I generate the WSDL to import in to Visual Studio I get various schema errors.

Checking the WSDL on third party sites all give me the same errors, they don't like the ns1 and ns2 references in there, I tried moving the main ns1 and ns2 references to the definitions section of the WSDL but no joy. Is this a bug? Is there something else I need to do now?

This is the same as this issue here: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F0000000AiQRIA0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to an update on the developer forum post this has now been acknowledged as a known issue. https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T5hiAAC, as the page says the workaround is to replace all instances of of "ns1:" and "ns2:" with "tns:"